# Redis out of memory, even with allkeys-lru policy

Tags: redis

I have a Redis server with `maxmemory 512MB` and `maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru` but once the server has filled up after a day of usage, I can't add any more items:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379[3]> set foooo 123
(error) OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory'.
```

IMHO that never should happen with the LRU policy.

I copied some server info to this Pasebin: http://pastebin.com/qkax4C7A

How can I solve this problem?

**Note:** I'm trying to use `maxmemory` because my Redis server is continously eating up memory even though *nearly* all keys have an expire setting and because `FLUSHDB` does not release system memory - perhaps this is related..

In the end I'm trying to use Redis as a cache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `info` output suggests that a lot of your server's memory is taken by Lua scripts:

```
used_memory_lua:625938432
```

Note that Lua scripts remain in memory until the server is restarted or [`SCRIPT FLUSH`](http://redis.io/commands/script-flush) is called. It would appear as if you're generating Lua scripts on the fly...

Comment: Seems like that was the problem, thanks. I wasn't aware that `eval()` scripts are kept in memory after having been executed.

Comment: RTFM ;) "Executed scripts are guaranteed to be in the script cache of a given execution of a Redis instance forever." - http://redis.io/commands/eval

Comment: yeah, you're right, but that's 12 pages for something that's seemingly simple and known from other languages (many languages implement `eval` but I don't know any other that stores that code in memory...)

Comment: The devil's in the details - glad it for sorted out for you though. BTW, are you generating scripts on the fly? I can't think of another reason for the Lua cache to become so big.

Comment: yes, I used `EVAL` to `INCR` a bunch of different keys, but reimplemented using `MULTI` now.

Comment: Good. Alternatively, you could still EVAL it but make sure that you pass the key names as arguments to a "static" script.